# Unescapable Periods in Apache 2.0 RewriteRule Regex

Tags: regex, apache, mod-rewrite, escaping

So, I have the following RegEx..

```
RewriteRule ^([-a-z0-9]*[A-Z\.]+.*)$ file.php?string=$1 [QSA]
```

The URL I want `file.php` to trigger for must either have capital letters or a period in it, then send the URL to the PHP script.

However, the problem I have is that this script is triggering on **any** URL, because of the not-truly-escaped Period.

I've tried escaping the period with a backslash, or two backslashes, or three... but none stop the generic interpretation.

What am I doing wrong?

**Edit:** As an example,

```
RewriteRule ^([-a-z0-9]*[A-Z\\.]+[-a-z0-9\/]*)$ file.php?string=$1 [QSA]
```

Doesn't work, but

```
RewriteRule ^([-a-z0-9]*\\.+[-a-z0-9\/]*)$ file.php?string=$1 [QSA]
```

does escape it.

**Edit 2:** Examples of URLs I want to redirect:

- /some-page-goes-here.html
- /heres-Robs/Old/Page/

And ones I don't:

- /testing/one/two/
- /an/actual-file.gif

**EDIT 3:** Old regex was:

```
RewriteRule ^([-a-z0-9]*[A-Z\.]+[-a-z0-9\/]*)$ file.php?string=$1 [QSA]
```

But while writing the post, I updated the question's regex to what you see above.

Comment: I take it this is in an `.htaccess`, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} [A-Z] [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \.html$
RewriteRule (.*) file.php?string=$1 [QSA]
```

When using mod_rewrite and you have several URLs to match, it is always better to use `RewriteCond` to filter and then apply your `RewriteRule`.

Comment: I'm not sure if I'm clear here.  I have URLs that lack capital letters and periods-- those I do not want to redirect.  However ones that also have capital letters OR periods, I want to redirect.  (if you'll note, all capital letters are +ed, and all lowercase/number-based ones are *ed.)

Comment: Can you edit your post and give some examples of what you want redirected, and what you do not want redirected? That will be simpler.

Comment: Jeez, I really have to look into the RewriteConds in the future.  Thank you very much!  Doesn't solve the non-greedy period, but it's something I would use instead.

Comment: I don't understand your "non greedy period", care to elaborate?

Comment: Originally, it looked like my regex was fine and correct-- the period was escaped, or even when double-escaped or not escaped at all should be treated as a literal period.  However, none of my regexes did as such-- leaving the period to either be greedy, or never treated as a literal period.  (make sense? :3 )

Answer (score 1):

I don't think your problem can be what you think it is: periods in a character class are supposed to mean literal periods, not "any character". If this really *is* the problem, somehow, then you could change `[A-Z\.]+` to `([A-Z]|\.)+`; but I doubt it. Some things to try:

- what happens if you comment out this line? does that successfully disable this redirect? if not, then obviously the problem isn't with this line. :-)
- what happens if you make this a real HTTP redirect, by changing `QSA` to `QSA,R`? Does the destination URL look like what you expect? Maybe there are some unexpected periods or uppercase letters? (Warning: this will very likely trigger an infinite redirect loop if you try it in a browser; it'll probably be easier to try submitting the request via port-80 Telnet and seeing the actual HTTP response.)

Also, your rule doesn't quite match how you describe it. For example, your rule wouldn't match a URL like `a.b.c`, because you only uppercase letters and/or dots to occur in a single "clump"; if they're separated by lowercase letters, no match will occur. Is that just because you didn't want to overcomplicate the description?

Comment: Notes:  1.  Thanks for the comment on the lowercase issue. I've updated the regex I'm developing to simply get greedy after [A-Z.]  I haven't updated the post to reflect this, but I will after this comment .   2.  If I do the replacement you suggest, it still correctly captures capital letters, but the period isn't treated literally-it's still a wildcard. (double-escaping stops this wildcard behavior, but doesn't allow periods.)   3. Commenting out the line stops the redirect, and ',R' doesn't fix the greediness.

Comment: @SoreThumb: Strange! (By the way, my point with `R` wasn't that it would change the regex behavior, but that it would let you see exactly what string the pattern was being applied to.)